# How to freeze a table header and everything above it when scrolling down?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been struggling with trying to **freeze a table header and everything above** it.
I've published a similar question and got an answer which I thought was good but eventually didn't do the trick.

Don't need cross browser support, just google chrome.

I'm trying to get this part of the html frozen when scrolling down:

```
<input>input1</input>
<input>input2</input>
<button>A</button>
<button>B</button>
<button>C</button>
<button>D</button>
<tr><th>header1</th><th>header2</th><th>header3</th><th>header4</th><th>header5</th></tr>
```

Here is the fiddle (please publish a fiddle basing on it with the answer):

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7wsSv/)

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean freeze as in stay in place while the table body scrolls? If so just add position:fixed in your css.

Comment: Yes I mean freeze, position:fixed doesn't do the trick entirely, it requires some more css and html changes. Publish a fiddle basing on mine if you can sort it out.thanks

Comment: Omer, I think you better look at this example `http://www.imaputz.com/cssStuff/bigFourVersion.html`

Comment: in my experience, this is basically impossible to do cross-browser in any manner that could be even generously called 'simple'. the easiest way is to use two tables; one with clickable headers and one with data and overflow containers. even then, col width usually need strict css or JS syncing to pull it off.

Comment: No interested in cross browser. just chrome

Answer (score 1):

Copy and paste this:

```
<div style="position:fixed; height:40px;">
<input>input1</input>
<input>input2</input>
<button>A</button>
<button>B</button>
<button>C</button>
<button>D</button>
<table >
    <tr ><th>header1</th><th>header2</th><th>header3</th><th>header4</th><th>header5</th></tr>
</table>
</div>
<p style="height:2000px; padding-top:150px;">hello</p>
```

Comment: This will not work properly. please play with the fiddlw I supplied, try to apply to it and see why. I'll be happy if you could sort it out

Comment: yes coz your inputs and button are out of table. either you bring them in or make a separate table for header and one for your content.

Answer (score 1):

```
.header-cont {
    width:100%;
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
}
.header {
    height:52px;
    background:#FFFFFF;
       margin:0px auto;
}
.content {
    width:960px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
       margin: 30px auto;
}

table {
    border-collapse:collapse;
}


td ,th{
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  border-top: 2px solid black;
  border-left: 2px solid black;
}

#t1 tr td{
    visibility:hidden;

}

#t2{
    padding-top: 42px;
display: block;

}
```

Here is a **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7wsSv/3/)**

Comment: The table header is not freezed in the fiddle you supllied.

Comment: doesn't work; if you scroll left or right, the cols don't line up. doh!

Comment: Please use the updated fiddle in my question, this will also not work well when the header field is smaller than the cell value

Comment: Fiddle Updated Once Again.. It's working fine... You need to Add table two times because the header size is not fixed so it's based on the contents.... Thanx